# addKeyListener() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, eclipse, keylistener

I have written this short class that is supposed to add an object of the "Player"
 class, which contains implemented KeyListener, but it seems that something is missing for the addKeyListener(); method.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Titlescreen {

    private Player player;

    public void init()
    {
        player = new Player();
        this.addKeyListener(player);
    }


    public void tick()
    {
        player.tick();
    }

    public void paint()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Titlescreen doesn't have an `addKeyListener(...)` method and does not extend any class that has this method, and so the compiler is rightly complaining that you're calling a method that does not exist for this class.

You have several options:

- Give Titlescreen an `addKeyListener(...)` method, but then you'll have to figure out what the method body should have, i.e., just what will you be adding the KeyListener to inside of the method body.
- Have Titlescreen extend a Swing component such as a JPanel, one that has its own `addKeyListener(...)` method. I'm guessing that this is what you wanted to do, but forgot to do this, but I'm not sure, given the information you've posted so far. Note that if you did do this, you will need to make sure that the listened to component is 1) focusable and 2) has the app's focus when you want the KeyListener to function.
- Just get rid of your `this.addKeyListener(...)` method call. Most important is the reason why you're even making this call, and perhaps something better can be done.

Comment: Another method of mine which I wrote while watching a tutorial, so I don't know which class I should extend or implement.

Comment: Do I need to implement "Runnable?"

Comment: @RobinatorJ: Runnable has nothing whatsoever to do with this issue.

Comment: @RobinatorJ: Consider checking out the Java Tutorials which you can find in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) under the beginner's resources section. The main tutorials will give you a good foundation in use of the language and an understanding of key concepts including methods, classes and inheritance.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Is there a class that is not using graphic components that contains the addKeyListener method? I already have another class with Canvas extended

Comment: @RobinatorJ: I don't understand your question above. Please elaborate on just what you mean by `"a class that is not using graphic components that contains the addKeyListener method"` as that is confusing to me. Also, if you are watching a tutorial that is showing you how to use the Canvas class, I'd recommend you stop watching it and find another tutorial as this one is 20 years out of date.